# Javascript regex: capture property name after array index

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, having a string representing an object property path which contains an array, what would be the best way to capture the property name after the array index with a regex?

Having this:

```
'someArray[0].property.otherIgnorableProperties'
```

I would be interested in capturing only the "property" portion, ignoring the "someArray[0]" portion, and everything that comes after "property" (including the dot). The "property" portion can have a limited number of possible arbitrary names.

So far I've tried this:

```
'someArray[0].property'.match(/^someArray\[\d\]\.property|someOtherPropertyName|otherName/g);
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Following cars10m answer I came up with this:

```
'someArray[0].field3.other'.match(/(?!someArray[\d+]\.)field1|field2|field3.*/g)
```

but this fails because for field3 it returns 'field3.other'. For field1 and field2 is working fine. Just to clarify, I need it to return the matched segment: field1, field2 or field3.

Comment: You could use a capturing group. Is there no other way to get that name than using a regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```js
let strings=['someArray[0].wantedprop1.otherIgnorableProperties',
             'dada[123].unwantedprop1.second.third',
             'X[91234].wantedprop2',
             'sameArray[94].wantedprop2.again',
             'sameArray[94].wantedprop2notwanted',
             'doNotTakeThis.wantedprop2.itIsNotAnArrayElement'
            ];
strings.forEach(str=>{
  let m=str.match(/.+\[\d+\]\.(wantedprop1|wantedprop2|anyotherwantedprop)(?!\w)/);
  let result=m&&m[1];
  console.log(result);
})
```

It returns the first capturing group as "the only surviving content" of the string, but only if the whole pattern matches.

The name of the array is not checked as yet, but you can do that by using the following RegExp instead:

```
/someArray\[\d+\]\.(wantedprop1|wantedprop2)(?!\w)/
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I modified it a little and finally I'm using it like this: /(?!someArray\[\d+\]\.)fieldName1|fieldName2|fieldName3.*/g

Comment: EDIT: I thought it worked at first, but after using it with match and running some tests, This 'someArray[0].field3.other'.match(/(?!someArray\[\d+\]\.)field1|field2|field3.*/) fails because it returns 'field3.other'

Comment: I was about to comment on that! But I will modify my solution to show you an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the "property" with the following regular expression in JavaScript flavor:

```
^'\w+[[]\d+[\]]\.(\w+)\.\w+'
```

Captures:

```
property
```

See link: https://regex101.com/r/s7yPpG/2